# How do I configure parameterized classes with arrays in puppet?

Tags: puppet

My goal is to define a class that takes, as input, an array of pairs. Since I'm not sure how to define an array of pairs, I'm just going to use a pair of arrays instead.

```
class student($username, $full_name){
  notify {"user":  message => "username: ${username}\n"}
  notify {"fullname":  message => "fullname: ${full_name}\n"}
  exec {'finger': command => "/usr/bin/finger ${username}", logoutput => true }
}

$users = ['elion', 'azee', 'root']
$names = ['El Lion', 'Avery Zee', "Rooty Root"]

class { 'student':
  username => $users,
  full_name => $names
}
```

Upon doing a 'puppet apply file.pp' I expect the output to iterate through the two arrays, printing out the notifications and fingering the students (that sounds horrible) in the order given by the arrays. I tried this and what ended up happening, is that puppet conflated the arrays into one string, so the $users value ended up being: `elionazeeroot` and the $names value ended up being `El Lion Avery Zee Rooty Root`.

Two questions:

1. Is there a way to define a class to handle a group of data, like I'm trying to do here?
2. I suspect that I'm not using the right construct to achieve my goal. What should I be doing instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/509075/puppet-variables-not-always-working

Comment: Hiera would probably make your life much easier. It's dead-simple to set up too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The natural way to represent your data in a programming language would be a hash like this:

```
$users = {
  elion => 'El Lion',
  azee  => 'Avery Zee',
  root  => 'Rooty Root,
}
```

While doing that in Puppet is possible, I've found it's best to decide what a resource definition for a single entry would be and then structure the hash as something you could pass to [create_resources()](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/function.html#createresources).  In this case, that would mean something like this:

```
define student ($full_name) {
  notify { "user ${title}":
    message => "username: ${title}\n",
  }
  notify { "fullname ${title}":
    message => "fullname: ${full_name}\n",
  }
  exec { "finger ${title}":
    command   => "/usr/bin/finger ${title}",
    logoutput => true,
  }
}

$users = {
  elion => { full_name => 'El Lion'   },
  azee  => { full_name => 'Avery Zee' },
  root  => { full_name => 'Rooty Root },
}

create_resources(student, $users)
```

*However*, as Ger notes, you'll be best off if you use [Hiera](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/latest/).  Hiera lets you separate your code (the manifest definitions) from your data (in this case, the particular names of the students).  In full, here's what I would do for your setup:

- Put the student data in a hiera file.  You can use JSON or YAML; I like YAML.  It would be something like this:

  ```
  classroom::users:
    elion:
      full_name: El Lion
    azee:
      full_name: Avery Zee
    root:
      full_name: Rooty Root
  ```
- Define a resource type for students and put it in `classroom/manifests/student.pp` in Puppet's `$modulepath`.  It would look like the `student` resource type above, but would be named `classroom::student`.
- Define a `classroom` class in `classroom/manifests/init.pp` with the following content:

  ```
  class classroom (
    $users = hiera('classroom::users', undef),
  ) {
    create_resources(classroom::student, $users)
  }
  ```

If you're using Puppet 3.x, the `hiera()` call in the class parameters is redundant, but you need it if you're still on Puppet 2.7.

Comment: This is pretty. I was going to try to do something similar with the new [lambdas](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/experiments_lambdas.html), but this is much nicer